# Make future elements (img) non draggable jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I was struggling with this and couldn't find an answer that works. I want to prevent someone from dragging an image on a page or make a right click on it (or future one that is displayed dynamically and save it.

I solved preventing right clicking through:

```
$(document).on('contextmenu', '.notRightClick', function(e){ return false; });
```

...but I can't disable draggable effect. I tried this : `'.notRightClick'.draggable( 'disable' )` but doesn't work for future elements.

**Update** Note: The img I want to drag has the class 'notRightClick :

```
<img class="notRightClick" src="someimgurl" alt="">
```

If anyone knows, that would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).on('contextmenu drag dragstart', '.notRightClick', function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Comment: drag doesn't work (at least on chrome), dragstart will

Comment: @A.Wolff: ah? I had assumed that `drag` was a custom jQuery UI event (triggered automatically), rather than a native event (which was silly of me, frankly). Added to the above code (and I already up-voted [@user3008011's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20901385/82548)).

Comment: Ok, dragStart doesn't work..should be lowercase -> dragstart and works fine!! Please amend and will select it as the right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('img').on('dragstart', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

Comment: Are you able to drag the google image in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zj5zb/)?

Comment: No I can't drag but your img doesn't have a class. Add a class to that image (eg : <img class="notRightClick" etc> and try again to disable drag on the class '.notRightClick"..doesn't work.

Comment: That's fine, but doesn't work on future elements. The answer of @David Thomas works but dragStart should be lower case otherwise won't work. Anyway, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is :

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.notRightClick', function(e){ return false; });
```

This disables the behaviour for mousedown which also includes the drag feature